# How can I check consumer lag for subject?

Tags: nats.io, nats-jetstream

I have Jetstream with two publishers for different subjects:

```
subject.a
subject.b
```

And one consumer for `subject.a`

I have some problems with checking lag of consumer for definite subject.
`/jsz?accounts=1&streams=1&consumers=1` shows sequence of all stream.

```
"delivered": {
   "consumer_seq": 1108,
   "stream_seq": 2216,
   "last_active": "2022-09-27T15:11:29.952186581Z"
}
```

So how can I see the sequence only for `subject.a` ?

I use sync `Publish` for publishers and `QueueSubscribe` for consumer.